# Setting Polycom device.net options in the config file

Tags: asterisk, polycom

I have several hundred Polycom SoundPoint IP phones and I need to make a config change to them. I would like to effect this config change through the XML config files that are loaded when the phone boots. I have found what the options are that I need to set, but Polycom's documentation is very unspecific about what this file should look like. They don't even really provide any sample XML.

In any case, the setting that I am looking to tweak specifically is:

```
device.set=1
device.net.etherVlanFilter.set=1
device.net.etherVlanFilter="Enabled"
```

According to the admin guide that can be found [here](http://supportdocs.polycom.com/PolycomService/support/global/documents/support/setup_maintenance/products/voice/spip_ssip_Admin_Guide_SIP_3_1.pdf) these device level options should be set in a separate file, but it gives no indication of what the file should look like.

Anyone out there have any idea? I've tried a few different things, but so far to no avail.

Comment: What firmware or phone models are you using?  The configuration changes when you move from the old sip software to uc software.

Answer (score 1):

The simple answer is to put the changes in the phone1.cfg file.

When the phone boots, it read the The Master Configuration File which is either [MAC].cfg (if you have created a per-phone config file) or if there is no [MAC].cfg then it uses the default 00000000.cfg provided with the firmware

This file contains amongst other things a list of config files to process and generally includes phone1.cfg and sip.cfg.

If you have set up a [MAC].cfg then it might also contain a phone-specific config file such as phone[MAC].cfg

So by putting the change in your phone1.cfg it will be picked up by all phones unless overriden by any per-phone config.

Comment: These settings never take effect when I put them in any of the standard config files. I've tried creating a new config file and addition it to MAC.cfg, but the problem really boils down to the fact that there is no sample XML with these settings. I'm not sure what the root node should be, so just shoving into existing files is mostly like a fruitless endeavor.

Answer (score 1):

If you are using [MAC].cfg files, it might look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- $Revision: 1.14 $  $Date: 2005/07/27 18:43:30 $ -->
<APPLICATION APP_FILE_PATH="sip_332.ld" CONFIG_FILES="5555.cfg, sip_332.cfg" MISC_FILES="" LOG_FILE_DIRECTORY="logs" OVERRIDES_DIRECTORY="" CONTACTS_DIRECTORY="" />
```

You specify in `CONFIG_FILES` to tell the phone to also load 5555.cfg for it's per-phone settings.

Here is a sample of 5555.cfg:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<!-- $RCSfile: $Revision: 1.121.4.11 $ -->
<phone>
  <reg
    reg.1.displayName="5555-1"
    reg.1.address="5555-1"
    reg.1.label="5555"
    reg.1.type="private"
    reg.1.auth.userId="5555-1"
    reg.1.auth.password="5555-1"
    reg.1.lineKeys="1"
    reg.1.callsPerLineKey="2"

    reg.2.displayName="5555-6"
    reg.2.address="5555-6"
    reg.2.label="Intcm"
    reg.2.type="private"
    reg.2.auth.userId="5555-6"
    reg.2.auth.password="5555-6"
    reg.1.lineKeys="1"
    reg.2.callsPerLineKey="1"
   />
  <msg msg.bypassInstantMessage="0">
  <mwi
    msg.mwi.1.subscribe="5555"
    msg.mwi.1.callBackMode="contact"
    msg.mwi.1.callBack="*2580"

    msg.mwi.2.subscribe=""
    msg.mwi.2.callBackMode="disabled"
    msg.mwi.2.callBack=""
   />
  </msg>
</phone>
```

Make sure you don't leave off the `<!-- $RCSfile: $Revision: 1.121.4.11 $ -->` or the phone won't realize it is a configuration file, even though you told it to load that file.

Now, as for the root tag, I have used all sorts of things.  I don't think it matters at all, so long as they match.

Comment: Just now see that someone posted a new answer to this a few months after I posted it. I don't honestly even remember what I was trying to do (vlan filtering, right?). Thanks for the answer though. I'll give it a try when I have a spare moment!

Comment: Hope it helps someone.  I even posted code!